# How to change symbols of points for PCA ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca

```
biplot<-ggbiplot(pcobj = PCA,choices= c(1,2),scale = 1,groups = Fdata$Tissue,ellipse = TRUE)+ 
geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 3)+geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = 3)
```

Comment: please provide an example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add `geom_point(aes(shape=factor(something)))`. For an example of `iris` data,

```
library(ggbiplot)

ir.pca <- prcomp(iris[,1:4], center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE) 

ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,groups = iris$Species, ellipse = TRUE)+geom_point(aes(shape=factor(iris$Species)))
```

[image]

```
ggbiplot(ir.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1,groups = iris$Species, ellipse = TRUE, labels = )+
  geom_point(aes(shape=factor(iris$Species))) +
  guides(color = "none", shape = guide_legend(title = "New"))  +
  scale_shape_discrete(labels = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

[image]

Comment: How can i remove groups from the legend and rename factors?

Comment: @SonamTashi Which legend do you want to remove? For example in my code, to remove colors, use `guides(color = "none")`, and to remove shape legends, use  `guides(shape = "none")`. And to rename title and factor name, I add the code above

Comment: furthermore, how can I change the title position and fonts of gg-plot for PCA?

Comment: @SonamTashi `theme(text = element_text(family = "mono"))` will change the font and `+ggtitle("aaa")` will add a title.

Comment: I changed the symbols using this argument +geom_point(aes(shape=factor(iris$Species). so how can i change the colour of the symbols so it also appears in the legend as well?